# Scipy Curve Fit Optimize not working for log scale values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

So I am trying to fit a set of data points to this equation:

abs(I) = Io(exp((qV)/(nKT)) - 1) --- Shockley diode equation

to a bunch of data points I was given. Knowing the V and the I values, I need to optimize the Io and the n values to get me data closely matching the data set I was given.

However, scipy optimize curve fit is not giving me the values I want, which is where n = ~1.15 and Io = ~1.8E-13, and is instead giving me n = 2.12 and I = 2.11E-11. I suspect this is due to the data set values being very small numbers, messing with the optimization, but even when i set the initial guess to be n = 1.15 and Io = 1.8E-13, the optimization values do not change.

Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


Voltage = np.array([-0.5 , -0.49, -0.48, -0.47, -0.46, -0.45, -0.44, -0.43, -0.42,
       -0.41, -0.4 , -0.39, -0.38, -0.37, -0.36, -0.35, -0.34, -0.33,
       -0.32, -0.31, -0.3 , -0.29, -0.28, -0.27, -0.26, -0.25, -0.24,
       -0.23, -0.22, -0.21, -0.2 , -0.19, -0.18, -0.17, -0.16, -0.15,
       -0.14, -0.13, -0.12, -0.11, -0.1 , -0.09, -0.08, -0.07, -0.06,
       -0.05, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02, -0.01,  0.  ,  0.01,  0.02,  0.03,
        0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,  0.09,  0.1 ,  0.11,  0.12,
        0.13,  0.14,  0.15,  0.16,  0.17,  0.18,  0.19,  0.2 ,  0.21,
        0.22,  0.23,  0.24,  0.25,  0.26,  0.27,  0.28,  0.29,  0.3 ,
        0.31,  0.32,  0.33,  0.34,  0.35,  0.36,  0.37,  0.38,  0.39,  0.4 ])
Current = np.array([  6.99000000e-13,   6.83000000e-13,   6.57000000e-13,
         6.46000000e-13,   6.19000000e-13,   6.07000000e-13,
         5.86000000e-13,   5.73000000e-13,   5.55000000e-13,
         5.37000000e-13,   5.27000000e-13,   5.08000000e-13,
         4.92000000e-13,   4.75000000e-13,   4.61000000e-13,
         4.43000000e-13,   4.32000000e-13,   4.18000000e-13,
         3.99000000e-13,   3.91000000e-13,   3.79000000e-13,
         3.66000000e-13,   3.54000000e-13,   3.43000000e-13,
         3.34000000e-13,   3.18000000e-13,   3.06000000e-13,
         2.96000000e-13,   2.86000000e-13,   2.77000000e-13,
         2.66000000e-13,   2.59000000e-13,   2.54000000e-13,
         2.43000000e-13,   2.33000000e-13,   2.22000000e-13,
         2.16000000e-13,   2.07000000e-13,   2.00000000e-13,
         1.94000000e-13,   1.85000000e-13,   1.77000000e-13,
         1.68000000e-13,   1.58000000e-13,   1.48000000e-13,
         1.35000000e-13,   1.21000000e-13,   1.03000000e-13,
         7.53000000e-14,   4.32000000e-14,   2.33000000e-15,
         6.46000000e-14,   1.57000000e-13,   2.82000000e-13,
         4.58000000e-13,   7.07000000e-13,   1.06000000e-12,
         1.57000000e-12,   2.28000000e-12,   3.29000000e-12,
         4.75000000e-12,   6.80000000e-12,   9.76000000e-12,
         1.39000000e-11,   1.82000000e-11,   2.57000000e-11,
         3.67000000e-11,   5.21000000e-11,   7.39000000e-11,
         1.04000000e-10,   1.62000000e-10,   2.27000000e-10,
         3.21000000e-10,   4.48000000e-10,   6.21000000e-10,
         8.70000000e-10,   1.20000000e-09,   1.66000000e-09,
         2.27000000e-09,   3.08000000e-09,   4.13000000e-09,
         5.46000000e-09,   7.05000000e-09,   8.85000000e-09,
         1.11000000e-08,   1.39000000e-08,   1.74000000e-08,
         2.05000000e-08,   2.28000000e-08,   2.52000000e-08,
         2.91000000e-08])

def diode_function(V, n, Io):
    kt = 300 * 1.38 * math.pow(10, -23)
    q = 1.60 * math.pow(10, -19)
    I_final = Io * (np.exp( (q * V) / (n * kt) ) - 1)
    return abs(I_final)


p0 = [1.15, 1.8e-13]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(diode_function, Voltage, Current, p0 = p0)

print(popt)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_title('I_d vs V_d')
ax.set_xlabel('V_d')
ax.set_ylabel('I_d')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.plot(Voltage, Current, 'ko', label="Original Data")
plt.plot(Voltage, diode_function(Voltage, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='best')



ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.set_title('I_d vs V_d')
ax.set_xlabel('V_d')
ax.set_ylabel('I_d')
ax.set_yscale('log')
popt = [1.15,1.8e-13]
plt.plot(Voltage, Current, 'ko', label="Original Data")
plt.plot(Voltage, diode_function(Voltage, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Picture of the graph:
[image]

The left graph is with scipy optimization and the right graph is the one I want

Comment: So when I cut out the last 15 values of my data set, it gives me a much better fit. not sure why the function believes the last couple values to be more important to fit than the beginning values

Comment: As usual with least-square fits the values which are larger are weighted more. The last values here are the values which are higher. To compensate this you may introduce a weighting in the fit. However, I don't think that is really a question about programming and might be off-topic here.

Comment: My question would be then how would I make the curve_fit weigh the lower values more. I tried using making the current data into logarithmic using `np.log10(Current)` and making the function `return np.log10(abs(I_final))`, but then the problem is the zero value in the Voltage with using logs

Comment: Quick note: scientific notation such as "kt = 300 * 1.38e-23" and "q = 1.60e-19" is faster than using the pow() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are on the right track, using the logarithm to scale the data such that the differences are much lower. In order to prevent problems with logarithms, one usual option is to add a constant. Instead of `log(x)`, one would use `log(x+constant)`. This constant needs to be 1 or higher.

Using different constants still gives different results though, again because larger values are weighted higher in the least-squares method.

```
# imports and data as in question

def diode_function(V, n, Io):
    kt = 300 * 1.38e-23
    q = 1.60e-19
    I_final = Io * (np.exp( (q * V) / (n * kt) ) - 1)
    return np.abs(I_final)

p0 = [1.15, 1.8e-13]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(diode_function, Voltage, Current, p0 = p0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('I_d vs V_d')
ax.set_xlabel('V_d')
ax.set_ylabel('I_d')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.plot(Voltage, Current, 'ko', label="Original Data")

offsets = [1,15]
colors = ["limegreen", "crimson"]
for offset, color in zip(offsets,colors):
    logdf = lambda V,n,Io: np.log10(diode_function(V, n, Io)+offset)
    poptn, pcovn = curve_fit(logdf, Voltage, np.log10(Current+offset), p0 = p0)
    ax.plot(Voltage, 10**(logdf(Voltage, *poptn))-offset, 
             color=color, label="fit (offset: {})".format(offset))

ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]